# Spark: rdd.collect() runs fine but rdd.take(5) throws an exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am relatively new to Spark. I installed spark in standalone mode on windows. When I try to use rdd.take(5), it throws following exception:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Eventhough, rdd.collect() runs successfully, rdd.take() throws an error. What can be the reason for this happening?

EDIT:
Adding my code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init("C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6")
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc = SparkContext()
data = sc.textFile("train.csv")
data.take(20)
```

EDIT2:
The first rows of data look like this: (Pasting partial part of the result I got using collect())

> [u'AnimalID,Name,DateTime,OutcomeType,OutcomeSubtype,AnimalType,SexuponOutcome,AgeuponOutcome,Breed,Color',
>   u'A671945,Hambone,2014-02-12 18:22:00,Return_to_owner,,Dog,Neutered
>   Male,1 year,Shetland Sheepdog Mix,Brown/White', 
>   u'A656520,Emily,2013-10-13 12:44:00,Euthanasia,Suffering,Cat,Spayed
>   Female,1 year,Domestic Shorthair Mix,Cream Tabby', 
>   u'A686464,Pearce,2015-01-31 12:28:00,Adoption,Foster,Dog,Neutered
>   Male,2 years,Pit Bull Mix,Blue/White',  u'A683430,,2014-07-11
>   19:09:00,Transfer,Partner,Cat,Intact Male,3 weeks,Domestic Shorthair
>   Mix,Blue Cream',  u'A667013,,2013-11-15
>   12:52:00,Transfer,Partner,Dog,Neutered Male,2 years,Lhasa
>   Apso/Miniature Poodle,Tan',

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Add more information like what is the source of your rdd.

Comment: Edit : Added code